# SQL-Bounce data in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I am an not a pro when it comes to SQL.I am looking for help write a single query that gives me bounce data for my sends in last 90 days. When I try the below I hit an error "Unable to create temporary data extension: Error: options.uri is a required argument"

I want to be able to see hard/soft bounces.

SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(EmailAddress) as EmailAddress, SubscriberKey
FROM _Subscribers
WHERE Status = 'bounced'

Thanks
Esha

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your query. It sounds like Query Studio was having a bad day. It does get a bit buggy at times. Your query will just give you people who've had a soft bounce on their last email, though. That bounce could have taken place 180 days ago and you'll miss those that hard bounced from a trusted ISP... they'll have a Status of "held". As alluded to below, if you want to know about the last 90 days, you'll need to look at the _Bounce Data View and join to _Subscribers to get the email addresses of the subscribers who bounced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Totally agree with other people mentioning _Bounce Data View. It is indeed better to have an overview an email bounces and a reason for them. Read [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_bounce.htm&type=5) for more information. Here is also how SQL would look like, adjust it based on your needs.

**Querying _Bounce as b and _Subscribers as s in the following SQL**

```
SELECT
    b.AccountID,
    b.OYBAccountID,
    b.JobID ,
    b.ListID,
    b.BatchID,
    b.SubscriberID,
    b.SubscriberKey,
    s.EmailAddress,
    b.EventDate,
    b.IsUnique,
    b.Domain,
    b.BounceCategoryID,
    b.BounceCategory,
    b.BounceSubcategoryID,
    b.BounceSubcategory,
    b.BounceTypeID,
    b.BounceType,
    b.SMTPBounceReason,
    b.SMTPMessage,
    b.SMTPCode,
    b.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID,
    b.TriggeredSendCustomerKey
FROM _Bounce b
LEFT JOIN _Subscribers s ON b.SubscriberKey = s.SubscriberKey
WHERE b.EventDate > DATEADD(D, -91, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to make it like documented [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_bounce.htm&type=5)  Email address is not a column in Bounce data view so if Email Address is related to SubscriberKey then you might want to modify your query as below and join _subscribers in case you want further details but it also does not contain email address

SELECT SubscriberKey from _bounce where
o.EventDate > dateadd(d,-90,getdate())